# Trigger with if condition in MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerchild
 AFTER INSERT ON category
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF(catagory.parent_id>0) THEN
 UPDATE catagory SET total_child=total_child+1 WHERE c_id=new.parent_id;
 END IF;
 END;
```

I have one category table in which I have `category_id`, `category_name`, `parent_id`, `total_child` and I want to increment `total_child` value after inserting child category.

I have make one trigger and try to increment its value after inserting child category but error has occurred.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Looking at the query, I see that the table is first called as `category` and after for each block, the table is called `catagory`. This could be the cause of the error you **haven't** posted

Comment: ooh sorry my mistake. Actually my table name is category. And i replace catagory to category but still error has occured.